# What's the Difference Between UQI and SSIM Measures for Image Similarity / Quality?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, measurement

I'm studying image quality assessment (IQA) problem and I'm currently learning about quality measures UQI and SSIM, I know UQI is a predecessor of SSIM, but they look exactly the same for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developers of both are the same hence the similarity is indeed "By Design".

The only difference is the addition of 2 constants in SSIM (C1 and C2).

The UQI:

[image]

The SSIM:

[image]

As the writers write in the SSIM paper:

[image]

Namely, UQI is a private case of SSIM for `C1 = 0` and `C2 = 0`.